# Facebook ShareDialog causes => Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null...}

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, onactivityresult

It's working fine, but when I click anywhere but the dialog so it would cancel, another dialog show which make me chose either to keep as draft or discard.! 
see pic below..!

If i chose **discard**  => it crashes..!?

I applied the extact same thing in here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

but here's the code:

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // this line is for facebook and it's causing the crash 
       callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


 // the ones below are for photoPicker and camera
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

      if (data != null) {

        Log.i("onActivityResult: ", data.toString() + "");

        final File file = new File(data.getData().getPath());

        if (file.exists()) {

          Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

          BSheetPost(myBitmap);
        }

        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            String.format("Saved to: %s, size: %s", file.getAbsolutePath(), fileSize(file)),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();


      }
    } else if (requestCode == PickConfig.PICK_PHOTO_DATA) {

      if (data != null) {
        ArrayList<String> selectPaths = (ArrayList<String>) data
            .getSerializableExtra(PickConfig.INTENT_IMG_LIST_SELECT);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectPaths.get(0));

        BSheetPost(bitmap);
      }


    } else if (data != null) {

      Exception e = (Exception) data.getSerializableExtra(MaterialCamera.ERROR_EXTRA);
      if (e != null) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }

  }
```

**Logcat**

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64207, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com***Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference
```

**Image**

[image]